# Preserve capitalization when rotating characters in a string

Tags: python

I need to edit my rotate function to consider capital letters and I am confused on how to do that

Below is my Python code:

```
from helper import alphabet_position, rotate

    def encrypt(text,key):
        #Declare variable
        cipher = ''

        #Compute length
        l = len(key)

        #Assign value
        idx = 0

        #Loop
        for i in text:
            #if condition satisfies
            if i.isalpha():

                #Call method
                cipher += rotate(i,alphabet_position(key[idx]))

                #Update to next 
                idx = (idx+1)%len(key)
            #Otherwise
            else:

                #Increment
                cipher += i

        #Return
        return cipher
    #Define main
    def main():



        #Get text from user 
        text = input("Type a message:" )

        #Get key from user
        key = input("Encrption key:" )

        #Call method
        cipher = encrypt(text,key)

        #Display result
        print(cipher)

    #Call main
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

But returns the following error

✖ ︎For vigenere.encrypt('Sailing <3 ships thru br0ken harbors',

```
    You should have returned this:                              
        'Feqwgba <3 fnvta effo ox0xiv syfvbxf'                  

    But you actually returned this:                             
        'feqwgba <3 fnvta effo ox0xiv syfvbxf'
```

✖ ︎For vigenere.encrypt('BaRFoo', 'BaZ')

```
    You should have returned this:                              
        'CaQGon'                                                

    But you actually returned this:                             
        'caqgon'
```

How do I get it to capitalize the first letter?

Alphabet position and rotation character are below:

```
import string

alphabet_pos = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def alphabet_position(letter):

    pos = alphabet_pos.index(letter.lower())
    return pos 

def rotate(letter, rot):
    pos = alphabet_position(letter)
    new_pos = (pos + rot) % 26
    new_char = alphabet_pos[new_pos]

    return new_char
```

Comment: In your code what is `s`

Comment: The problem isn't capitalizing the first letter though, is it? Look at the exepcted output in case 2; it has two capitals in the middle of the word too.

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, please make sure you represent your indentation accurately. If people have to guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems in your code.

Comment: Please, show us your `alphabet_position` and `rotate` methods. Seems the problem is hidden there.

Comment: I've nominated your question for reopening, as it has enough information to answer. In `alphabet_position()` you use `letter.lower()` to make everything lowercase to encrypt. If you do this, you need to afterwards `upper()` any characters that were originally uppercase (checkable with `.isupper()`).

Comment: Also, you're missing the key from the first test example

Comment: @divibisan I've rolled back your changes. While it did help readability, edits [should not substantially change the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question), which your edit did.

Comment: quickfix: `return cipher.capitalize()`

Comment: @TemporalWolf I disagree. The only substantive change was moving the linked files into the main block of code, which is pretty much a necessity if you want the code to be testable. Everything else was just removing blank lines, redundant comments, and fixing improper indentation.

Comment: @divibisan you don't make askers' code testable! You don't even make it _runnable_. You'll never know if you're making part or all of the problem disappear.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Fine, that's a good point. Perhaps I was overzealous.

Comment: There is a never used line `l = len(key)`. Though `len(key)` arises again, could be replaced or omitted.